# oracle: how does table() construct have access to values from joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to understand the table() construct and baffled by how it has access to the cell values from another joining table. In the query below, **data.key** from the **data** table is available within the scope of **x**.

```
with data (key, val) as
(
  select '5', 200 from dual
)
select * 
from 
  data 
   join
  table
  (
    cast
    (
      multiset
      (
        select level from dual 
        connect by level <= data.key /* how is data.key available within an alien scope? */
      ) AS SYS.odcinumberlist
    )
  ) x
  on (data.key = x.column_value);
```

How is it done?

Comment: How do correlated sub-queries work?  table data is available to any 1 level removed by engine design.  Table x can access table data as it's within 1 level.  Nest x again and x would not be able to access table data.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Is this feature specific to table () construct alone or is there any other construct that has the same feature?